# C++ strlen function bug

Tags: c++

I have encountered a very weird bug, i don't know why is this happening and visual studio says it is a bug in the cpp language file "xstring". it tells me it is something with the `strlen()` function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string args;
    string file;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(argv); i++) {
        args = args + argv[i];
    }
    if (args.empty()) {
        while (true) {
            cout << "Specify A Path To An App.\n";
            cout << ">>>";
            cin >> file;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Loading File... " << argv[1] << "\n";
    }
}
```

I tried to find a solution but no solution worked.

Comment: `sizeof(argv)` doesn't do what you think it does. You got `argc` for that prupose.

Comment: For future questions, please provide [mcve], including complete error message that you get (copied and pasted into the question as text).

Comment: `argv` is a pointer. The size of a pointer is the size of the pointer itself, not what it might point to.

Comment: Also, almost always there will be at least 1 argument - the path to the executable as it was called. Your `if` might not work as you expect.

Comment: As for the "bug" it's probably a crash, because you likely use invalid or out-of-bounds elements of the `argv` array (like the null pointer that's specified to always be at `argv[argc]`). If you catch it in a debugger you must walk up the call stack until you come to your own code to find out when and where in your code it happens.

Comment: And technically speaking, infinite loops are *undefined behavior*. You must have some way of breaking out of a loop.

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> args(argv+1, argv+argc);` makes it a little easier in C++ to work with command line arguments passed to the program.

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(argv)` is not the number of arguments but the number of bytes  of a pointer `char**`. You should use the argument `argc` to retrieve the number of arguments.

Comment: @Maciek Source files `.cpp` is usually not directly executable. What tool are you using to execute that?

Comment: I Am Using Visual Studio 2022

Comment: The only thing that i know is: It is the for loop error and argc is not equal to the count of arguments (it should be 4)

Comment: @Maciek You do take into account that first argument is the name of the executable? So `./MyProgram Arg1 Arg2 Arg3 Arg4` will have `argc == 5`.